# Arduino ethernet capabilities and limitations

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I'm currently working on a small project to make a device that collects data, and then sends it out over a network, probably after all of the measurements have been made in the initial version (a few 10s of MB after a couple of days), although I could potentially want to expand on some of the capabilities at a later date.

I was wondering if the ethernet capabilities of an Arduino (I know there's a variety of different types) are good enough for this kind of application, or should I look into something with a bit more oomph, such as a RasPi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Arduino but keep on mind that depend the arduino type the ram is very limited, I think that a few 10s of MB should not be problem if the project will evolve and include more function maybe use RasPi will be a good option.
Regards